# Check element exists using PHP Selenium 2 Webdriver?

Tags: php, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to check if an element on a page exists by CSS using Selenium 2. Anyone have any examples using PHP Selenium Webdriver [Facebook](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver) wrapper?

I have tried the below code:

```
if($driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath("image-e4e")) != 0)
{
}
```

But gives me this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'NoSuchElementWebDriverError' with
>   message 'Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"image-e4e"}

Answer (score 17):

By design, `findElement` returns the WebDriverElement if it is found but it throws an exception when it is not found.

To check whether the element is on the page without getting an exception, the trick is to use `findElements`. `findElements` returns an array of all elements found on the page. It returns an empty array if nothing is found.

```
if (count($driver->findElements(WebDriverBy::xpath("image-e4e"))) === 0) {
  echo 'not found';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use: `$driver->findElements` intstead of `findElement`

findElements will return an empty array if element not exists and will not throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `sizeof()` builtin function in PHP:

```
$check = $driver->findElements(WebDriverBy::xpath('image-e4e'));
if (sizeof($check) > 0) {
    echo "success";
}
```

OR can also be used to `count()` function:

```
if (count($driver->findElements(WebDriverBy::xpath('image-e4e'))) > 0) {
    echo "success";
}
```

**Output:** If XPath element is available on a page then it will give you success

---

If you want to use `findElement` then:

```
$checkXpath = 'image-e4e';
$checkXpath = $this->findElementByXpath($driver, $checkXpath);
$check = $driver->findElement($checkXpath);
if (count($check) > 0) {
    echo "success";
}
```

OR

```
$checkXpath = WebDriverBy::xpath('image-e4e');
$check = $driver->findElement($checkXpath);
if (count($check) > 0) {
    echo "success";
}
```

**Output:** If XPath element is available on a page then it will give you success

---

**Note:** The `findElement` method throws a *NoSuchElementException* exception when the element is not available on the page. Whereas, the `findElements` method returns an empty list when the element is not available or doesn't exist on the page.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your xpath is bad.

If you want to continue using xpath, then your seletor would be

```
//*[@id='image-e4e']
```

If you have an open mind, get used to CSS Selectors. They are [faster and much more readable](http://sauceio.com/index.php/2011/05/why-css-locators-are-the-way-to-go-vs-xpath/)

```
WebDriverBy::cssSelector("#image-e4e")
```

This is of course assuming that the ID is `image-e4e`.  The reason your xpath was failing was because xpath was attempting to locate an immedate child with tag name `image-e4e`. you want to parse the entire pom for an element with an attribute that equals `image-e4e`. Whether that's ID or name, I do not know.

Comment: It still gives me the error of uncaught exception. At the time I test the element is not on page, so I want to check if it doesnt exist.. if the element exists I dont get error..

Comment: I tried both WebDriverBy::xpath("//*[@id='image-e4e']")) and WebDriverBy::cssSelector("#image-e4e")... any other ideas..

Comment: I was thinking of some sort of assert function, but not really sure.. seems like a very straightforward thing to do...but cant quite figure it out

Answer (score 0):

```php
//https://www.guru99.com/images/1/073118_0611_Installatio8.png
if (count($crdriver->findElements(WebDriverBy::xpath('//*[@id="topOfPag"]/div[7]/div[1]/h1'))) === 1) {
    echo 'con1';
} else if (count($crdriver->findElements(WebDriverBy::xpath('//*[@id="topOfPage"]/div[7]/div[1]/h1'))) === 1){
    echo 'con2';
}else {
    echo 'fail';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if($driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id("image-e4e")) != 0)
{

}
```

Try the above logic I am sure definitely it will work out.